# Java: get parameters like are Sent in One String, using get method

Tags: java, servlets

I have this URI:

```
http://IP5:port/notification/myServlet.do?method=myMethod&param1=[08]&method2=anotherParam&param0=[07,04,06]
```

I want to obtain the URI's last part in the same order:

```
method=myMethod&param1=[08]&method2=anotherParam&param0=[07,04,06]
```

But' I can't discover how:

I can see in the `request` the field `input`, in order to do a substring after of `?` character...

the methods:  `request.getRequestURI()` and `request.getRequestURL()` is not working for me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `request` is an `HttpServletRequest`. If so, you should be able to get what you are looking for using [`request.getQueryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString()).

Comment: Muchas gracias.